# set file permission to android

Tags: android, fonts, permissions, file-permissions

I am not able to paste the *.ttf(font file) file in system root of my funbook micromax tablet.
so how can i set permission of this system folder. or is there any other option to install font to my device.
Actually am trying to install kannada font to my device for one app.
but i dont know actual work so please help me.

> adb push

&

> adb pull

does any body know??

Comment: You can install fonts like this Settings->Display->Font Style and click "Get fonts online"

Comment: i am using micromax funbook tablet and in that Font Style is not a option.
Please tell me some good ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you need a rootet android to get Access to `/system/fonts`

Comment: i am able to go to the root folder but not able to edit that folder.

Comment: When you have a rootet phone you can paste the .ttf-file in the Folder. If its not rootet you have no Access to insert/edit/read

Comment: i am using Micromax funbook tablet(P300) ver:4.0.3 
how can i do that rootet for this???

Comment: This is something for the XDA Forum :). You should Google it. But beware of a lost guarantee or a bricked device